# Makefile assign variable passed from command line

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to assign a variable that has also been passed from the command line?

I tried the following Makefile:

```
testvar := newassign

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $(testvar)
```

If I execute `make`, the output is the expected `newassign`. However, if I execute `make testvar=asd`, the output is `asd`, while I expect this to also be `newassign`.

I use GNU Make 4.1.

Comment: Try the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Values.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently an intentional feature. Command line options always have precedence over  assignments inside the Makefile. If you want to force assignment, you can use `override`.

```
override testvar := newassign

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $(testvar)
```